# Cache Oblivious Matrix Transposition Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, transpose

I have implemented an in-place cache-oblivious matrix transposition algorithm in C++ as below:

```
void CacheObliviousTransposition(int x, int delx, int y, int dely, int N, int* matrix) {
    if ((delx == 1) && (dely == 1)) {
        int tmp = matrix[(N*y) + x];
        matrix[(N*y) + x] = matrix[(N*x) + y];
        matrix[(N*x) + y] = tmp;
        return;
    }

    if (delx >= dely) {
        int xmid = delx / 2;
        CacheObliviousTransposition(x, xmid, y, dely, N, matrix);
        CacheObliviousTransposition(x + xmid, delx - xmid, y, dely, N, matrix);
        return;
    }

    int ymid = dely / 2;
    CacheObliviousTransposition(x, delx, y, ymid, N, matrix);
    CacheObliviousTransposition(x, delx, y + ymid, dely - ymid, N, matrix);
}
```

However, when I called the below method after transposition to ensure that it worked correctly, the if loop is being entered so I'm assuming something must be wrong with the implementation.

```
void CheckTransposition(int N, int* matrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[(i*N) + j] != (j*N) + i + 42)
            {
                cout << "Transposition failed at i=" << i << ", j=" << j << "\n";
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me identify what is wrong?

Note: variable matrix is a dynamically assigned integer array as below, as matrix is stored row by row in N*N consecutive memory locations

```
int* MatrixInit(int N)
{

    int* matrix = new int[N*N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            matrix[(i*N) + j] = (i*N) + j + 42;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: `(matrix[(i*N) + j] != (j*N) + i + 42)` What is this supposed to do? You're comparing a value in the matrix to a value computed outside the matrix. Is that deliberate? Also just a side note, but an `assert` would probably serve your purposes more directly than `if (...) cout ...`

Comment: @Ike sorry my bad I've just added the code I use to initiate the matrix to the question

Comment: Do you have to perform the algorithm in-place? If so, the basic way you are swapping won't work as far as I see it. If you create a new matrix to store the transposed output, it becomes a lot easier.

Comment: @Ponsietta You could have just done this: `std::vector<int> matrix(N*N); std::iota(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), 42);`; and saved yourself the manual dynamic allocation and the `for` loops.  Also, you have `std::swap` instead of the code you have now to swap an element.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the reason I'm not using vector is that this is an assignment that requires us to code without using existing data structures

Comment: @Ponsietta Then `std::iota(matrix, matrix + N, 42);`

Comment: ...Or if you cannot use `std::iota` too, `for(int k = 0; k<N*N; ++k) { matrix[k] = k + 42; }`.

Comment: That makes sense sure. I can update that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code will transpose your elements twice. For example, once CacheObliviousTransposition reaches the single element [0,1], it will transpose it with [1,0]. However, a separate recursion will later on reach [1,0], and transpose that with [0,1] again. Ultimately, all elements will be back in their original places.

To ensure that elements are only transposed once, you could check that x is less than y before switching:

```
void CacheObliviousTransposition(int x, int delx, int y, int dely, int N, int* matrix) {
    if ((delx == 1) && (dely == 1)) {
        if(x<y)
        {
            int tmp = matrix[(N*y) + x];
            matrix[(N*y) + x] = matrix[(N*x) + y];
            matrix[(N*x) + y] = tmp;
        }
        return;
    }

    if (delx >= dely) {
        int xmid = delx / 2;
        CacheObliviousTransposition(x, xmid, y, dely, N, matrix);
        CacheObliviousTransposition(x + xmid, delx - xmid, y, dely, N, matrix);
        return;
    }

    int ymid = dely / 2;
    CacheObliviousTransposition(x, delx, y, ymid, N, matrix);
    CacheObliviousTransposition(x, delx, y + ymid, dely - ymid, N, matrix);
}
```

Comment: +1 OMG, checking if `x < y` prior to the swap is such a simple solution. I'm embarrassed that I didn't see it. I was so focused on making the base case less granular.

Comment: @Ike Thanks. I think there might be a more optimal solution that avoids some recursion. The above version is very granular like you said, and it is possible to ignore half the cells.